# Ruby: Getting nth element from each sub array in a 2d Array

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, watir, watir-webdriver

As part of our test suite in Watir we are verifying a table of data.
One of the requirements is that a particular column must be empty (unless a particular radio button is selected)
So in my script, I have the following code

```
incidents = browser.table(:xpath, Xpath_CC).strings
```

where browser is a watir-webdriver browser object
Gives my this 2d array in Incidents

```
[["DateTime", "Problem", "Value", "Compared", "Number", "Causes", "Where", "Count", "Type"],
["May 07, 02:15 - 02:30", "Web", "38.46 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
["May 07, 02:15 - 02:30", "Video", "40 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
["May 07, 02:00 - 02:15", "Email", "30 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
["May 07, 01:00 - 01:15", "Email", "70 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
["May 07, 01:00 - 01:15", "Email", "70 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
["May 07, 01:00 - 01:15", "Email", "0 %", "", "1", "UNKNOWN", "", "1", "J105"],
]]
```

What I need to do is check each "Compared" column in each sub array and make sure it is empty.
I could do something like

```
 result = true
 incidents.each do |row|
   if (row[3] != '')
    result = false
  end
end
```

Put that is my Java brain telling me how to do it. I figure t´here must be a simpler one line ruby way of doing this

Comment: Oops figured it out, something like
incidents.transpose[3][1..-1].inspect will give me what I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One-liner:

```
result = incidents.all? { |row| row[3].empty? }
```

To skip header information:

```
result = incidents[1..-1].all? { |row| row[3].empty? }
```

Comment: The only problem with that solution is that it doesn't factor in the header information

Comment: If I do something like this, I get the right answer
incidents = incidents[1..-1]

assert(incidents.all?{ |row| row[3].empty? }, "Some Error Msg")